# Digital certificate in client and server model

Tags: cryptography, certificate, client-server

I am doing an assignment where I must design a client-server model for a gas station. Without the digital certificate part, what happens would be:

1. Initially, I create a database in MySQL which has 3 things: card type (debit/credit), card number, and card status (true/false or valid/invalid).
2. The client inserts his card, indicates it is a debit or credit and the number of the card.
3. The server checks the card against what it has in the database. If the type along with the number matches and the status is valid, it allows the client to proceed to choose the gas and so on.

But now with the digital certificate coming in, the instructor wants me to generate a certificate for the client side and the server side. The server will keep its digital certificate together with the CA public key from the CA. The client also save its digital certificate the public key of the CA and save it. The client and server exchanges the digital certificate. Each side verify the digital signature using the CA’s public key. I am a little bit confused of how to design this. I can generate a digital certificate for each side, but then does a new certificate get generated on the client side each time someone puts a card in? I was thinking since the server needs to verify the users of the gas station rather the the client side itself. Or the client and server verifying each other?

Comment: *...but then does a new certificate get generated on the client side each time someone puts a card in...* These are good questions to ask yourself, congratulations. Remember that certificates are primarily used to authenticate endpoints (like servers and terminals) and people. You have all three in this scenario, so it is hard to figure out what your instructor wants. My guess is that the client certificate is to authenticate the card-reading terminal. In that case you just generate the certificate once for the terminal, maybe include the serial number of the terminal in the subject name.

Comment: I say this because it is usually the terminal that authenticates the person using the card. In fact in the USA there is usually no authentication at all: if you have the card you can use it.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your answer. I will dig deeper to get a better grip of this thing.